# Como retornar a diferença em horas entre duas datas?

Tags: php

Tenho duas datas armazenadas nas variáveis `$date1` e `$date2` respectivamente. Elas estão no formato:

YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM

Gostaria de saber como eu pego a diferença em horas entre essas duas datas?

Comment: Qual o banco? ou quer fazer isso no PHP?

Comment: Fazer no PHP rsrs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) para saber o intervalo entre duas datas, para saber a diferença em horas, você obtém a diferença em dias e multiplica por *24*.

```php
$datatime1 = new DateTime('2015/04/15 00:00:00');
$datatime2 = new DateTime('2015/05/16 00:00:00');

$data1  = $datatime1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data2  = $datatime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$diff = $datatime1->diff($datatime2);
$horas = $diff->h + ($diff->days * 24);

echo "A diferença de horas entre {$data1} e {$data2} é {$horas} horas";
```

[**`Exemplo`**](http://ideone.com/1Q22DM)

Comment: Acabei de aplicar o seu método. Ele funciona bem, porém ele não é exato em questão de horas. Por exemplo, tem um intervalo de 16 horas entre as datas, ele vai interpretar isso como 0 dias, e ao multiplicar por 24 vai dar 0, e não 16 entende? Somente nestam parte que estou com problemas, de resto ele funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Agora sim funcionou perfeitamente. E para minutos seria assim? `$minutos = $diff->m + ($diff->days * 1440);`

Comment: @Guilherme Acho que só basta multiplicar as horas por *60*, veja um [exemplo](http://ideone.com/HoepOj).

Comment: Perfeito! Resolvido :) Muito obrigado.

Comment: Amigo não estão alterando os resultado "minutos" se modificados a hora e minutos em  $datatime2

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime("tomorrow");

$interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
```