# Retornar em horas a diferença entre duas datas em JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Acabo de ver [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64240/como-retornar-a-diferen%C3%A7a-em-horas-entre-duas-datas) aqui no Stack Overflow que mostra como resolver meu problema mas em PHP. Gostaria de saber como posso calcular a diferença entre 2 datas e mostrar isso em horas. ex:

```
var d1 = new Date('2015-12-21 00:00:00').toTime();
var d2 = new Date('2015-12-19 00:00:00').toTime();
var df = Math.abs(d1-d2);

//?? agora preciso saber como retornar "48:00:00"
```

Alguém tem uma luz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Galera pra resolver meu problema, acabei criando uma função assim:

```
function timeDiff(d1, d2) {
    var d1 = new Date(d1).getTime();
    var d2 = d2 || new Date().getTime();
    var df = Math.abs(d1 - d2);
    var td = {
        d: Math.round(df / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), //dias
        h: Math.round(df / (60 * 60 * 1000)), //horas
        m: Math.abs(Math.round(df / (60 * 1000)) - (60 * 1000)), //minutos
        s: Math.abs(Math.round(df / 1000) - 1000)
    };
    var result = '';
    td.d > 0 ? result += td.d + ' dias ' : '';
    td.h > 0 ? result += ('0' + td.h).slice(-2) + ':' : '00:';
    td.m > 0 ? result += ('0' + td.m).slice(-2) + ':' : '00:';
    td.s > 0 ? result += ('0' + td.s).slice(-2) : '00';
    return result;
}
```

Essa função vai pegar a data que vc enviar (em formato padrão para data `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) e calcular a diferença entre a primeira e a segunda data. NOTA: na função coloquei para que se enviada somente uma data, ele calcule usando a data atual para facilitar o serviço na minha aplicação...

Answer (score 7):

```
> df/1000/60/60
```

df dividido por 1000 (para retornar o número de segundos), divido por 60(para retornar o número de minutos), dividido por 60 (para retornar o número de horas).

Se quiser em dias, divida por 24, ai você vai ter 2 (dias), como resultado.

Comment: ok, que eu devo chegar a fazer o calculo. mas tinha entendido que havia um método melhor que esse...

Answer (score 4):

Vê se este código te ajuda:

```
data1 = new Date('2014/01/01');
data2 = new Date('2014/04/01');
var diferenca = Math.abs(date1 - date2); //diferença em milésimos e positivo
var dia = 1000*60*60*24; // milésimos de segundo correspondente a um dia
var total = Math.round(diferenca/dia); //valor total de dias arredondado 
var emHoras = Math.round(total*24); // valor total em Horas
console.log(emHoras);
```

Ele calcula a diferença em horas.

Comment: sim ele calcula mas vai me dar um valor inteiro sobre quantas horas. preciso saber também para minutos e segundos porque nesse sistema será feito um controle de SLA