# Calcular em formato de hora

Tags: javascript

Preciso de ajuda para criar um calculo de horas.
Tenho um campo:

```
Hora inicial <input id="inicial")>
Hora final <input id="final">
Total de horas <input id="resultado">
```

Consigo somar valor inteiros(00), porem como fica em formato de horas(00:00) dá erro o cálculo.

Sei muito pouca coisa de JavaScript, alguém pode da uma força?

Tentei isso:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function calcular(){
   var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value, 10);
   var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value, 10);
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = n1 - n2;   
} 
</script>
```

Se eu passo um valor da seguinte forma:
14:00 para n1
16:00 para n2

Ele não exibe o 2 que é o resultado.

Quero saber quanto tempo tem entre 14:00 e 16:00.

Preciso saber apenas a diferença no mesmo dia, não irá passar de 24h por isso não posso passar data e retornar hora. como sugerido.

Comment: Seria bom [edit] sua postagem e acrescentar mais detalhes como o que tentou fazer, quais os dados que tem e qual resultado quer obter. Aqui tem alguns links que podem ajudar no aproveitamento do site: [Tour] | [Ask]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Retornar em horas a diferença entre duas datas em JAVASCRIPT](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104969/retornar-em-horas-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-duas-datas-em-javascript)

Comment: Qual é o formato aceite em "hora inicial" e "hora final"? Só inteiros ou minutos também como `14:35`por exemplo?

Comment: minutos também.