# JavaScript Diferença entre datas

Tags: javascript, data

Estou fazendo um script que precisa retornar o tempo (hh:mm:ss) entre duas datas. A primeira data é fixa, já a segunda é a data atual.

Através [deste *post*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104969), consegue retornar essa diferença de datas (em horas) porém, o resultado não está correto.

Conforme imagem abaixo, o valor dos minutos e segundos não estão corretos, o correto seria retornar `05:06:36`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo segue código utilizado. Tenho que fazer alguma conversão nos minutos e segundos?

```js
function timeDiff(d1, d2) {
    var d1 = new Date(d1);
    var d2 = d2 || new Date();
    var df = Math.abs(d1 - d2);
    var td = {
        d: Math.round(df / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), //dias
        h: Math.round(df / (60 * 60 * 1000)), //horas
        m: Math.abs(Math.round(df / (60 * 1000)) - (60 * 1000)), //minutos
        s: Math.abs(Math.round(df / 1000) - 1000)
    };
    var result = '';
    td.d > 0 ? result += td.d + ' dias ' : '';
    td.h > 0 ? result += ('0' + td.h).slice(-2) + ':' : '00:';
    td.m > 0 ? result += ('0' + td.m).slice(-2) + ':' : '00:';
    td.s > 0 ? result += ('0' + td.s).slice(-2) : '00';
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que usar [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) para arredondar sempre para baixo (em vez de [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), que dependendo do caso pode arredondar para cima).

Além disso, é preciso descontar os totais de dias, horas e minutos da diferença, antes de fazer a próxima divisão. Por exemplo, se eu tenho 130.000 milissegundos, dividindo por `60 * 1000` e arredondando, terei 2 horas. Então eu tenho que descontar essas duas horas (ou seja, subtrair 120.000 milissegundos do total), para que sobre 10.000 milissegundos (que equivalem a 10 segundos). O mesmo vale para os dias e horas, então ficaria assim:

```js
function format(valor) {
    return valor.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

function timeDiff(d1, d2) {
    var d1 = new Date(d1);
    var d2 = d2 || new Date();
    var df = Math.abs(d1 - d2);
    let d = Math.floor(df / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // dias 
    df -= d * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // desconta o total de dias
    let h = Math.floor(df / (60 * 60 * 1000)); // horas
    df -= h * 60 * 60 * 1000; // desconta o total de horas
    let m = Math.floor(df / (60 * 1000)); // minutos
    df -= m * 60 * 1000; // desconta o total de minutos
    let s = Math.floor(df / 1000); // segundos
    var result = '';
    if (d > 0) result = `${d} dias `;
    return `${result}${format(h)}:${format(m)}:${format(s)}`;
}

let d1 = new Date('2020-10-13T07:04:59');
let d2 = new Date('2020-10-13T12:11:35');
console.log(timeDiff(d1, d2)); // 05:06:36
```

Também mostrei outra opção para formatar os valores, usando [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), além do uso de [*template string*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) como alternativa à concatenação de strings.