# Comparação de datas php

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia amigos!

Meu objetivo é comparar duas datas em PHP.

Eu quero verificar se a $data1 é 24 horas maior que a $data2. Como faço isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Bom dia Igor, pode se explicar melhor?

Comment: Bom dia, Leadnnd. Imagine duas variáveis de data, eu quero compará-las e saber se a primeira data é 24 horas maior que a segunda, como faço isso?

Comment: De acordo com esse seu comentário, para saber a diferença entre minutos é assim: `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2019-05-01 10:00:00', '2019-05-01 10:05:00') ; `

Comment: Faça como o @adventistaam disse!

Comment: Não, Anderson! meu problema é diferente.

Comment: @IgorSouza Quais as diferenças? Você pediu para comparar datas, a questão citada compara datas. Para mim pareceu o mesmo problema - ou talvez a sua pergunta não está clara.

Comment: Ou você pode ver essa resposa [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64245/54152), acho que atende o que você quer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia Igor!

**Isto apenas vai dar se tiver BD! Este programa não funciona em *PDO (PHP Orientado a Objetos)*!**

**NOTA:** No final coloquei um `if` que vai comparar os dois valores. Existem várias formas de fazer. Eu coloquei esta porque achei que fosse a mais simples de compreender.

Experimente fazer da seguinte forma:

> ```
> <?php
> $data1 = "" \\colocar o valor da data1
> $data2 = "" \\colocar o valor da data2
> $sql = "SELECT DATE_ADD(".$data1.", INTERVAL +1 DAY) AS data1_edit FROM tabela"; \\faz a consulta na BD
> $consulta = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); \\faz a conexão com a BD através da variável $connect
> $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
> $data1_edit = $result['data1_edit']; \\vai buscar a variável data1_edit ao SELECT feito em cima
> if ($data1_edit == $data2) {} \\serve para comparar as duas datas
> ?>
> ```

Boa sorte!

Comment: Muito obrigado, querido! me ajudou demais! perfeitamente o que precisava.

Answer (score -1):

Outra sugestão seria que:

Você pode usar com PDO:

```
<?php

   class Horas_DAO {
      private $conn = null;
      public function verificaDatas($data1, $data2) {
          require_once "conexao_pdo.php";   
          $retorno = 0;
          $this->connection = Connection::getConn();
          $query = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, :data1, :data2) horas";
          $stmt->bindValue( ':data1', $data1, PDO::PARAM_STR );
          $stmt->bindValue( ':data2', $data2, PDO::PARAM_STR );
          $stmt->execute();
           try{
              if ($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
                 $retorno = $row['horas'];        
               }
           }catch( PDOException $e ){
              echo "Problema: ".$e->getMessage();
             exit();
           }
          return $retorno;

      }
   }

?>
```

Ai você precisaria chamar o método da classe:

```
 <?php

       $ad = new Horas_DAO();
       $r = $ad->verificaDatas('2019-05-01 10:00:00', '2019-05-01 10:05:00');
       if( $r > 24 ){
           // faz algo
        }
  ?>
```

Comment: Por que usar o banco de dados para calcular a diferença se o PHP já faz isso?

Comment: É apenas uma opção

Comment: Que faz sentido nenhum alguém usar. Existe alguma vantagem?

Comment: É verdade, você tem razão.